# Django get and use instance and field name on upload_to

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a path for a FileField, getting and using the instance to get another data for the URL, plus the field name, to get something like:

```
/media/documents/<instance_data>/<field_name>.pdf
```

My best working approach is:

```
class UserDocFileField(models.FileField):

    def get_fixed_folder_path(self, instance, filename):
        return 'documents/{}/{}.pdf'.format(instance.user.rfc, self.name)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["upload_to"] = self.get_fixed_folder_path
        super(UserDocFileField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And in my model:

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    file_1 = UserDocFileField()
    file_2 = UserDocFileField()
    # ... other documents
```

Giving me what I'm looking for, i.e.:

```
/media/documents/ABCD840422ABC/file_1.pdf
```

However, this makes Django to generate a migration file every single time I run makemigrations, I have tried to set it as an inner class, rewriting the super as

```
super(Documents.UserDocFileField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But, I got this error:

```
NameError: name 'Documents' is not defined
```

So, is there a way to avoid the generations of migrations files or a better approach to solve this?

Comment: Do you really need this as a custom field? Why not a standard FileField with `upload_to` set?

Comment: Is there a way to get the Instance inline?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `instance` is a parameter that is passed to the `upload_to` callable.

Comment: Yes, of course, I know that, but, I only know the way of getting it via function, like `def get_upload_path(instance, filename):` but still need the field_name or a way to send a third parameter with the final filename.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use a custom class for the `upload_to` itself, with a `__call__` method to make the instance callable. In order to make that serializable for migrations you then need to add a `deconstruct` method. So:

```
class UploadTo:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def __call__(self, instance, filename):
    return 'documents/{}/{}.pdf'.format(instance.user.rfc, self.name)

  def deconstruct(self):
    return ('myapp.models.UploadTo', [self.name], {})

class Documents(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
  file_1 = FileField(upload_to=UploadTo('file_1'))
  file_2 = FileField(upload_to=UploadTo('file_2'))
```

Honestly though, at this point I'd probably just write separate `upload_to` functions for each field.

Comment: Wow... this is what I was looking for, I had them as you suggest, on separate `upload_to` functions, but, there was like 15-20 field for 4 different models that require almost the same, this is why I was looking for a short solution, easy to mantain.

Comment: Excellent answer @Daniel Roseman - thank you! Just one point, I believe there is a typo in your example in that in the def deconstruct(self), the reference should be [self.name] instead of [self.fieldname]?